# Short Story - Exploding Mountain with Alien Craft Inside, Nearby Town Residents are Killed and Preserved

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I seem to recall a story from (maybe) an anthology in the late 80s or early 90s, about some teens or kids who discover an alien spacecraft in a mountain which explodes, killing everyone in the nearby town.

The explosion released a tremendous amount of radiation and preserved everyone's bodies.

The main character is a man who feels guilt over his role in the explosion, and had never told anyone except his friends, who were in the mountain at the time of the explosion.

He goes on to become an expert in this explosion. Eventually, he goes to kill himself by laying down in bed with his parents (who had died and were preserved by the explosion), removing his protective gear in order to do so.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! You may want to look at the answers to [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/80867) for ideas on additional information to [edit] into your question. For example: When did you read the story? What format was it in (a book, collecting short stories? a magazine? online?)? If in physical form, how old was the book or magazine? Do you remember the cover? With respect to the story itself, do you recall any details of the preservation, or why lying down with his dead parents would result in his death?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SF&F!  Can you help us out a bit by adding some more details, for example approximately when you read the story?  There's a [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) that might suggest other questions you can answer.

Comment: It must have been late 80s early 90’s - I think it may have been in an anthology.

Comment: I think the explosion released a tremendous amount of radiation and it also preserved everyone’s bodies. The main character - a man, felt guilt at his role in the explosion and never told anyone except his friends who were in the mountain at the time of the explosion...

Comment: He had to remove his gear in order to lie down with his parents. - it might have been in one if the best sci fi shortof”